# R pasteing data errors

Tags: r, copy, dataset, copy-paste, paste

I'm pulling my hair out because I need data sets input into R for a test but some of them are just too big to input by hand like i've been getting away with up until now. Every time I try and paste one of the teacher's data sets it shows up in error below each row. It doesn't do this for my friend on his mac (I have windows) and I have tried deleting and redownloading, even from another server! I've also tried imputing the data in excel first and that didn't work either. please help, I don't know what I can do differently.

[data set from web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ksmm.png)

[errors in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8oot.png)

Comment: Can you explain your process for pasting the data into R? What are you trying at the moment?

Comment: Have you tried saving it as a csv and reading it in with something like `read.csv`? That is usually where people start, rather than with copy pasting. What error do you get if running that code?